# Why is onblur not working?

Tags: javascript, html, onblur

I have an HTML form and I need an email confirmation field so I tried this:

```
[contact-field label='Email' type='email' id="email" required='1'/]
[contact-field label='Confirmar email' type='email' id="confemail" onblur="confirmEmail();" required='1'/]
```

I also have this JavaScript at the end of my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmEmail() {
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value
        var confemail = document.getElementById("confemail").value
        if(email != confemail) {
            alert('Email Not Matching!');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Why is onblur not working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the generated html

Answer (score 4):

`[contact-field label='Confirmar email' type='email' id="confemail" onblur="confirmEmail();" required='1'/]` is not valid *html*. I think you might be using some technology that generates html. In such a case `onblur` might be lost in the translation (i.e not be generated on the html).

Comment: Looks like WordPress syntax to me.

Answer (score 0):

This may be able to help (asp.net).  This example adds up the total value of given controls and sets the value of the TotalScore TextBox to that value whenever the controls that have this onblur event loose focus

Adding event to control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="GroupA" runat="server" onblur="Javascript:RecalculateScoreTotal();"  Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
```

JavaScript:

```
        function RecalculateScoreTotal() {
        var tbA = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=GroupA.ClientID%>').value.replace(/,/g,''));
        var tbB = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=GroupB.ClientID%>').value.replace(/,/g, ''));
        var tbC = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=GroupC.ClientID%>').value.replace(/,/g, ''));
        var tbD = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=GroupD.ClientID%>').value.replace(/,/g, ''));
        var tbE = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=GroupE.ClientID%>').value.replace(/,/g, ''));
        var tbF = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=GroupF.ClientID%>').value.replace(/,/g, ''));
        var tbG = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=GroupG.ClientID%>').value.replace(/,/g, ''));
        var total = tbA + tbB + tbC + tbD + tbE + tbF + tbG;
        document.getElementById('<%=TotalScore.ClientID%>').value = total;
    }
```

Hope it helps